# OpportunityContactRole data access

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I'm trying to get the name of a person from an opportunitycontactrole... is that possible or completely off base? This is the code that I already have. I realize that getting the contactID from the contactRole isn't returning a name... What would i need to have there instead to get a name?

```
trigger add_primary_advisor on Opportunity(before update) {

for(Opportunity o: Trigger.new){

     if (!Trigger.oldMap.get(o.id).IsClosed) {
       OpportunityContactRole contactRole =
            [select ContactID from OpportunityContactRole where IsPrimary = true and OpportunityId = :o.id];
       if (contactRole != null) {
         o.Primary_Advisor__c=contactRole.contactID;
       }
     }
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 //If Contact.Name doesn't works try fetching Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName 
   List<String> names = new List<String>();
    for(OpportunityContactRole contactRole =
        [select Contact.Name from OpportunityContactRole where IsPrimary = true and OpportunityId = :o.id]){
      names.add(contactRole .Contact.name)
  }
```

Comment: When i try assigning the results of that query to a list of strings, i get an error saying that it's returning OpportunityContactRoles

Comment: SF Query results return List of type Sobject, so you wont be able to do that. I have edited my  code above to answer your needs